# Adapting the page's backgroundColor (that can be changed anytime) to a button's backgroundColor in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `ArbitraryBtn` that changes the page's color into random colors on every click:

```
import React from 'react';

export const changeToArbitraryColor = () =>
    (document.body.style.backgroundColor =
        '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));

const ArbitraryBtn = () => (
    <button
        className='arbitrary-btn'
        onMouseDown={changeToArbitraryColor}></button>
);

export default ArbitraryBtn;
```

And I also have this `AppendBtn`. I want the `AppendBtn` to have the same background-color as the document's page. So I did this on the `style` attribute:

```
import React from 'react';

const AppendBtn = () => {
    return (
        <button
            className='append-btn'
            style={{ backgroundColor: document.body.style.backgroundColor }}>
            +
        </button>
    );
};

export default AppendBtn;
```

But the problem with this is that it only takes the background-color of the page when the component is mounted, and when I click on the ArbitraryBtn and it changes the background-color of the page, the AppendBtn doesn't adapt to the new background-color of the page anymore.

I tried exporting a function (so that I could call this function inside the changeToArbitraryColor function) that uses useRef hook for the `style` attribute. But since React Hook "useRef" cannot be called at the top level and React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function, and 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level, it didn't work out.

Here's a gif when I was using JavaScript (but I want to do this in React):
[image]

The button on the left side is the `ArbitraryBtn` and the one on the right is the `AppendBtn`. How can I achieve this in React? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this:

Idea is once the body background is changed on click of the `ArbitraryBtn`. The same time I am passing a state to the child component `isClicked`. Now every time `isClicked` changes/ toggles my `useEffect()` in the child component will get invoked. At that very time, I am setting the background of the `AppendBtn` same as the body background using normal javascript :)

**Codesandbox Demo:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/button-issue-h6h2l?file=/src/App.js

**FULL CODE:**

```js
const { useEffect, useRef, useState }=  React;

function App() {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(true);
  const changeToArbitraryColor = () => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor =
      "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    setIsClicked(!isClicked);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ArbitraryBtn changeToArbitraryColor={changeToArbitraryColor} />
      <AppendBtn isClicked={isClicked} />
    </div>
  );
}

const ArbitraryBtn = ({ changeToArbitraryColor }) => (
  <button className="arbitrary-btn" onClick={changeToArbitraryColor}>
    I am here
  </button>
);

const AppendBtn = ({ isClicked }) => {
  const childRef = useRef(null);
  console.log("Here I am");
  console.log(document.body.style.backgroundColor);
  useEffect(() => {
    childRef.current.style.backgroundColor =
      document.body.style.backgroundColor;
  });
  return (
    <button className="append-btn" ref={childRef}>
      + I am the Append Button
    </button>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello @Imran. I like your approach for this. But I forgot to consider that I have a dozen of other color buttons that also changes the color of the page. When the arbitrary button's clicked, it works. But when I click on my other color buttons, AppendBtn's bgcolor doesn't change since it's dependent on the Arbitrary button only. So is there a way that the change of AppendBtn's bgcolor is not dependent on the Arbitrary but on the page instead? Please help.

Comment: Hi @Zedd : Do one thing. Share you full project containing all these buttons - that you have ! Will need to look at the generic solution for this ! There are ways obviously :-D Share the codesandbox link containing other buttons as well ! `With small small changes great things are achieved` . I am actually very busy today and tomorrow. If I get time I will fix this for u, If not after 2 days only :)

Comment: Nvm @Imran. I just put the concept of what you did on the `ArbitraryBtn` to my other btns. Thanks. By the time I'm able to finish the app that I'm working on, I wanna share it with you;)